# Find a basis of $\mathbb{F_5^5}$ in which the matrix has the Jordan normal form

Tags: jordan-normal-form

I have the following task:

Let $A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
\end{array}
\right) \in M_5(\mathbb{F_5})$.

Find a basis of $\mathbb{F_5^5}$ in which the matrix A has the Jordan normal form.

My first question: Can I consider $\mathbb{F_5^5}$ as modulo 5? So as the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

My solution:

I computed the characteristic polynomial:

$(1- \lambda)^2(2- \lambda)^3$. So the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$.

Now, I computed the dimension of the eigenspaces.

$\dim(\ker(A-Id))=2$

$\dim(\ker(A-2Id))=2$

So since I know the eigenvalues and the dimension of the corresponding eigenspaces I could write the jordan matrix, right?

So:

$J= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{array}
\right) $

Is that right?

That what is still unclear to me is:

- What is meant by a basis of $\mathbb{F_5^5}$?

Comment: Just as usual Jordan basis when working over $\;\Bbb R\;$ or $\;\Bbb C\;$ : basis of eigenvectors and, for $\;\lambda=2\;$, added one generalized eigenvector...

Comment: Sorry, it isn‘t clear for me. Would my solution be right?

Comment: Yes, your solution for the JNF of the matrix seems to be right. My comment above was for the way to find a Jordan basis...